# How to subtract 24hrs from FieldValue.serverTimestamp() of firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I need to pass two values to the `Firebase Cloud Function`

The first one is the `current Timestamp` and the second is `Timestamp` `24 hrs` back.

I am getting the current Timestamp using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, but **how to subtract 24hrs** from `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`?

I need the Final result in the same format as `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`.

My whole code is in java

If there is another solution please refer to it but the main thing is that I want to perform an operation on the server timestamp

Comment: I changed my code as I got a more feasible solution by using the Firebase Cloud function but still wants these two values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help but found an alternate solution. I am not sure that it is the correct way but it works for me.

`Date currentTime = new Date(Timestamp.now().getSeconds() * 1000);`

`Date currentTime24hrsBack = new Date(Timestamp.now().getSeconds() * 1000 - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`

`new Timestamp(currentTime24hrsBack).toDate()`

`new Timestamp(currentTime24hrsBack).toDate()`

`import com.google.firebase.Timestamp;`

Comment: You are still performing math on client side timestamp, not server side.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to perform date math on `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` directly.  It returns a static token value (not a Timestamp object at all) that gets interpreted on the server at the time of a write.

If you want to compute some time relative to a server timestamp value, you will have to:

1. Write the `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`
2. Read it back from the document as a Timestamp object
3. Perform time math on the Timestamp's component values (seconds) to create a new Timestamp with the desired time
4. Write the new timestamp to the document

Comment: I need to update both values at the same time as there is another task-based on these two values

Comment: That won't be possible with a direct write from the client.  You would have to go through a backend that doesn't need a server timestamp and can generate its own dates reliably.   That backend can generate both dates, assuming that its own clock is believed to be accurate.

Comment: If your other value is always 24hrs before the timestamp, why not calculate it in the other task rather than store the two values?